# BibLaTeX: Make all non-Latin characters appear in grey color

Tags: biblatex

If I wanted my BibLaTeX style to do the following for all non-Latin characters, how should I modify it?

[image]

The bibtex code:

```
@book{makajev1966probljemy,
  title = {Probljemy lingvistichekogo analiza: Fonologija, grammatika, ljeksikologija Проблемы лингвистического анализа: Фонология, грамматика, лексикология [Problems of linguistic analysis: Phonology, grammar, lexicology]},
  author={Makajev Макаев, E. A. Э. А.},
  address = {Moscow Москва},
  publisher = {Nauka Наука},
  year = {1966}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code that shows the entry in that format (withouth grey, of course)?

Comment: Minimal code from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` with the suitable call of `biblatex`, otherwise it's guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XeLaTeX to compile you can use the `ucharclasses` package. This package provides the command `\setTransitionsForCyrillics` with two arguments. The first argument is executed when the font changes to Cyrillic, the second argument is executed when the font as no longer Cyrillic. In this case you can use the following:

```
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\color{gray}}{\color{black}}
```

To prevent the `\color` command in the transitions from gobbling spaces you can add an empty group.

```
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\color{gray}}{\color{black}{}}
```

Note however that comma's, semicolons etc. are seen as latin, so they will not be colored.
MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{makajev1966probljemy,
  title = {Probljemy lingvistichekogo analiza: Fonologija, grammatika, ljeksikologija Проблемы лингвистического анализа: Фонология, грамматика, лексикология [Problems of linguistic analysis: Phonology, grammar, lexicology]},
  author={Makajev Макаев, E. A. Э. А.},
  address = {Moscow Москва},
  publisher = {Nauka Наука},
  year = {1966}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\color{gray}}{\color{black}{}}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
Dual script citation: \cite{makajev1966probljemy}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you actually want all non-latin characters (such as Greek, Arabic, CJK etc) to have a different color then you can use `\setTransitionsForLatin` instead.

Comment: This works, but like it's shown on your result, there's a spacing problem. I fixed it by the following code: 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script = Cyrillic, Color = 808080]{Times New Roman} 
\usepackage{ucharclasses} 
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\cyrillicfont}{}

Comment: @Ian indeed, I did not spot the spacing problem. This is fixed in the answer now by adding an empty group after the color switch. I tried your solution as well but it colors too much, for example Makajev and [Problems of ...] are also gray (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSw2h.png) so I left it out of the answer for now. If you can solve this or provide a complete MWE that doesn't show this problem then I'm happy to incorporate it in the answer, but you can also add a new answer on your own since it is essentially a different approach.